# Launched when a game is started by a shortcut, how can I find Steam again, after ending the game, in order to stop it too?

Tags: debian, process, steam, background

I start a *Steam* game by its shortcut. Then when I end the game, I would like to stop *Steam* after that game too.

Under *Windows 7* I used once, I had to do an `Alt-Tab` to find *Steam* and stop it by its *Quit* menu entry. But under *Debian*, `Alt-Tab` or `Windows key` doesn't show me the *Steam* application running in background : but it is here, because if I start the system monitor I see it among the processes.

My workaround is to use the `Windows key`, type *Steam* and launch its GUI : its current active instance comes. Then I stop it by *Quit* and *Steam* is removed.

But is there a way to retrieve the *Steam* instance more quickly to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

In my desktop environment (GNOME), there is a Steam icon in the top right hand corner of the menu bar while Steam is running. Clicking on it brings Steam to the foreground.

If your desktop environment has no such visual indicator then you may need to kill it from a terminal. The process name appears to be "`steam`", so a `pkill steam` should do it, or at least grab its attention.